# How can I create the material design shadows in SVG using SVG filters

Tags: svg, material-design, svg-filters

I have found [this SVG](http://orig04.deviantart.net/3862/f/2014/297/b/c/material_design_shadows_for_inkscape__svg__by_shiningwingpony-d83zd2q.svg) that creates some of the shadows but it only works in Chrome (Firefox and Safari on OS X do not display the shadows)

I'm trying to reimplement the visual look of Material Design in pure SVG for a project and I'm interested in a solution that follows as much of the design requirements from [Elevation Shadows section](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#) in the Material Design Specs.

I have programatic control over the generated SVG so, if the parameters of the filters are easier to express in computations based on elevation, please specify so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a comprehensive drop shadow filter structure that duplicates all the functionality of the drop shadow control in Photoshop. I wrote a mini-app to allow you to change any of these parameters and copy and paste the resulting filter: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/sJopz

```
<filter id="drop-shadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="-50%" y="-50%" height="200%" width="200%">

<!-- Take source alpha, offset it by angle/distance and blur it by size -->
<feOffset id="offset" in="SourceAlpha" dx="-5.49" dy="-5.11" result="SA-offset"/> 
<feGaussianBlur id="blur" in="SA-offset" stdDeviation="4.75" result="SA-o-blur"/>

<!-- Apply a contour by using a color curve transform on the alpha and clipping the result to the input -->

<feComponentTransfer in="SA-o-blur" result="SA-o-b-contIN"> 
  <feFuncA id="contour" type="table" tableValues="0 1"/> 
</feComponentTransfer>

<feComposite operator="in" in="SA-o-blur" in2="SA-o-b-contIN" result="SA-o-b-cont"/>

<!-- Adjust the spread by multiplying alpha by a constant factor --> <feComponentTransfer in="SA-o-b-cont" result="SA-o-b-c-sprd"> 
  <feFuncA id="spread-ctrl" type="linear" slope="2.4"/> 
</feComponentTransfer>

<!-- Adjust color and opacity by adding fixed offsets and an opacity multiplier --> 
<feColorMatrix id="recolor" in="SA-o-b-c-sprd" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 .8 0" result="SA-o-b-c-s-recolor"/>

<!-- Generate a reasonably grainy noise input with baseFrequency between approx .5 to 2.0. And add the noise with k1 and k2 multipliers that sum to 1 --> 
<feTurbulence result="fNoise" type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="6" baseFrequency="1.98"/> 
<feColorMatrix in="fNoise" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 7 -3" result="clipNoise"/> 
<feComposite id="noisemix" operator="arithmetic" in="SA-o-b-c-s-recolor" in2="clipNoise" k1="0" k2="1" result="SA-o-b-c-s-r-mix"/>

<!-- Merge the shadow with the original --> 
<feMerge> 
  <feMergeNode in="SA-o-b-c-s-r-mix"/> 
  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
</feMerge> 
</filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter chain does not appear to be valid so you should report a bug on Chrome. Firefox is doing the right thing by not displaying anything.

For instance in the first filter chain (the one with id="filter4284") two of the  feGaussianBlur elements require an input of something called "composite" e.g.

```
  <feGaussianBlur
     id="feGaussianBlur4338"
     in="composite"
     stdDeviation="1"
     result="blur" />
```

but there's no result in that chain called composite so the filter chain fails. The other chains are similarly broken.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest version I could find is the following:

```svg
        <filter style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB;" id="height-1" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="400%">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0.5" flood-color="rgb(0,0,0)" result="flood"></feFlood>
          <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" result="comp"></feComposite>
          <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" result="offset"></feOffset>
          <feGaussianBlur in="offset" stdDeviation="1" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur>
          <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blur" mode="normal"></feBlend>
        </filter>
```

The only things that change from one elevation to the other are the `dy` in `feOffset` and the `stdDeviation` from `feGaussianBlur`. In both cases, the value for the elevation is the value they take.

The `x` and `y` of the filter are set to generous margins in order to avoid cutoffs in large elevation (e.g. 24)

Comment: If you want a cut and paste filter - just use this shadow generator I wrote: http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/sJopz

Comment: Wow @Michael , that generator is amazing. Please write and answer with the filter structure and the link to the codepen so I can accept.